# C++11 nested class is faster than separate class why

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, inner-classes

i have one question but the answer i did not find it. I wrote some combinatorics solver and separate piece of main save structure to separate into class called Matrix. Which i filled in backtrack algorithm. When I create a new instance of pointer to Matrix and often call method set and unset on class Matrix performance decrease 2 times. It become 2x slower than before. But if i create nested class, performance will be ok. But i don`t know why? Is it any  solution how to have separate class without nested class, but performance will be ok? Thank you for your time. I paste Matrix.h and Matrix.cpp. Project I tested on macOsx and linux compiled by g++ 4.2.1 with -O2 declaration

```
        class Matrix {
        private:
            int rows;
            int columns;
            int filledCells = { 0 };
            int * data = nullptr;
            int * freeCellInColumn = nullptr;
        public:
            Matrix(int rows, int columns);
            ~Matrix();
            void set(const int & column, const int & value);
            void unset(const int & column);
            int & get(const int & row, const int & column);
            int & getFreeCellsInColumn(const int & column);
            int getFilledCellsInColumn(const int & column);
            int * getData();
            const int & getFilledCells() const;
    };
```

and definition is

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Matrix.h"

Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int columns) {
    if (rows < 1 || columns < 1) {
        std::runtime_error("Number of rows or columns at matrix is invalid.\n");
    }
    this->rows = rows;
    this->columns = columns;
    this->data = new int [rows * columns]();
    this->freeCellInColumn = new int[columns]();
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        this->freeCellInColumn[i] = this->rows;
    }
}

Matrix::~Matrix() {
    delete [] this->data;
    this->data = nullptr;

    delete [] this->freeCellInColumn;
    freeCellInColumn = nullptr;
}

void Matrix::set(const int & column, const int & value) {
    this->data[(--this->freeCellInColumn[column]) * this->columns + column] =    value;
    ++this->filledCells;
}

void Matrix::unset(const int & column) {
    this->data[(this->freeCellInColumn[column]++) * this->columns + column] = 0;
    --this->filledCells;
}

int * Matrix::getData() {
    return this->data;
}

int & Matrix::get(const int & row, const int & column) {
    return this->data[row * this->columns + column];
}

const int & Matrix::getFilledCells() const {
    return this->filledCells;
}

int & Matrix::getFreeCellsInColumn(const int & column) {
    return this->freeCellInColumn[column];
}

int Matrix::getFilledCellsInColumn(const int & column) {
    return this->rows - this->freeCellInColumn[column];
}
```

I paste the piece of nested class what i mean by nested class in Labelling class mean declaring class Matrix in class Labelling,
method int * getData() i use only for print result just once.

```
class Labelling {
private:
    class Matrix {
        private:
            int rows;
            int columns;
            int filledCells = { 0 };
            int * data = nullptr;
            int * freeCellInColumn = nullptr;
        public:
            Matrix(int rows, int columns);
            ~Matrix();
            void set(const int & column, const int & value);
            void unset(const int & column);
            int & get(const int & row, const int & column);
            int & getFreeCellsInColumn(const int & column);
            int getFilledCellsInColumn(const int & column);
            int * getData();
            const int & getFilledCells() const;
    };
    TextPrinter * printer;
    NSumProblemSolver * solver;
    Matrix * solution;
    ...};
```

Comment: _"But if i create nested class"_ Can you elaborate please? I can't spot any nested class in your code.

Comment: What you call "declarations" are actually *definitions* of the member functions. You *declare* them inside the class definition. For example, `int * getData();` is a *declaration*. `int * Matrix::getData() { return data; }` is a *definition*.

Comment: As for your question, what do you mean by "nested class"? Do you mean that you *define* the function *inline* in the class definition? Then that *inline* part could be an explanation for your speedups. The compiler is able to call your functions *inline* which saves a n actual function call and might lead to further optimizations.

Comment: sorry for my mistake i fix the declaration and definition. Nested class i class declare in other class like as class A{  private: class B{ ...}; b * bstructure = nullptr; }

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve]. I also don't see any benchmarking code anywhere

Comment: How about the *definitions* of the `Labelling::Matrix` member functions? Are they implemented in the same source file as the rest of the `Labelling` member functions? Then the compiler can still do some inlining and other optimizations, that's not possible if you split the code into multiple [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).